# MySQL phpmyadmin - SELECT FOR UPDATE not recognised

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, row-level-security

I'm writing a PHP program and wanna to implement row-level locking to avoid concurrent user update/delete for the same record.

But I hit error "Unrecognised keyword" when using SELECT FOR UPDATE. Table type is innoDB.

Am i missing any setup for my database?

[image: My SQL statement]

```
SELECT * FROM companyTable
WHERE companyId = "0000001"
FOR UPDATE;
```

[image: SQL Error]

Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "FOR" at position 57)
SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT * FROM companyTable WHERE companyId = "0000001" FOR LIMIT 0, 30
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3
```

Comment: what is `FOR` ??

Comment: SELECT [...] FOR UPDATE is Oracle database syntax not MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> **There Is an Syntax Error Try this:**

**Its Select All Records From 1 - 30**

```
SELECT * FROM companyTable WHERE companyId = "0000001" ORDER BY id LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: I'm trying to use SELECT FOR UPDATE statement which it lock a record/prevent from other user to perform UPDATE/DELETE action.

Answer (score 0):

First problem seems to be, that in your SQL query is missing keyword `UPDATE`

> `SELECT * FROM companyTable WHERE companyId = "0000001" FOR LIMIT 0, 30`

And the second issue can be, that syntax `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in MySQL doesn't support  `LIMIT`.

So your SQL query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM companyTable WHERE companyId = "0000001" FOR UPDATE
```

In phpmyadmin, it is difficult to remove auto added `LIMIT` clause - try another MySQL client.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is not build to handle(Test) transaction control, use Mysql Console or php session instead

and use "begin" to start the **Transaction** before the code

```
begin;

select * from `tblx` where `idx`=1 for update;

update `tblx` set `field`='xx' where `idx`=1;

commit;
```